# Solve the differential equation: $\frac{dy}{dx } =x \frac{ d^{2} y}{ dx^{2} } +\ln(1+\frac{ d^{2} y}{ dx^{2} })$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation:

$\frac{dy}{dx } =x \frac{ d^{2} y}{ dx^{2} } +\ln(1+\frac{ d^{2} y}{ dx^{2} })$

Answer (score 4):

Let $v=\frac{dy}{dx}$. Then
$$v=xv^{\prime}+\ln(1+v^{\prime})$$
$$v^{\prime}=v^{\prime}+xv^{\prime\prime}+\frac{v^{\prime\prime}}{1+v^{\prime}}$$
Then either $v^{\prime\prime}=0$, $v^{\prime}=C_1$, $v=C_1x+C_2$,
$$C_1x+C_2=C_1x+\ln(1+C_1)$$
So $C_2=\ln(1+C_1)$, $$y=\frac12C_1x^2+x\ln(1+C_1)+C_3$$
Or $v^{\prime}=-1-\frac1x$, $v=-x-\ln|x|+C_1=\frac{dy}{dx}$, $$y = -\frac12x^2-x\ln|x|+C_3x+C_2$$
Substituting into the original differential equation we get
$$-x-\ln|x|-1+C_3=-x-1-\ln|x|$$
So it follows that this is the singular solution only possible for $x<0$ and $C_3=0$, so actually
$$y=-\frac12x^2-x\ln|x|+C_2$$
is the singular solution.